# app:dex DEBUG error in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting this error everytime I try to run the android project

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Build.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Build.gradle module:app file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "java.ui.application3.android.learn.hisab"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental = true;
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
//    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6'

}
```

There are no errors in the entire app. Please help me out
I tried the following:
1. Clean and Build the project again
2. Invalidate Caches/restarts
3. multiDexEnable true

No effects...

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You missed `multidex` in `app\gradle`.

> dependencies {
>   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0    ...